# how to avoid #{...} replaced in custom maven archetype?

Tags: maven-archetype

Here is a mybatis mapper.xml in my custom maven archetype :

```
...
<sql id="selectSql">
    <where>
        <if test="id != null">
            id = #{id}
        </if>
        <if test="parentId != null">
            and parent_id = #{parentId}
        </if>
 ...
```

mybatis symbol  #{..}  not maven archetype symbol ${...} , the problem is mapper.xml goes wrong in replacing #{...} to #..., lose {}  after new maven project by custom archetype :

```
<sql id="selectSql">
    <where>
        <if test="id != null">
            id = #id
        </if>
        <if test="parentId != null">
            and parent_id = #parentId 
        </if>
```

i named only 2 propertyies key as follow , having nothing to do with mybatis mapper xml :

```
<requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="projectName">
        <defaultValue>hntest</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
    <requiredProperty key="ConstantClassName">
        <defaultValue>HnTestConstant</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
</requiredProperties>
```

why maven archetype fileter {...} and how to avoid this problem?

Comment: i can't filter out this file, because some code need to be replaced inside.